# Xamarin Android C# "iCursor does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-cursor

I've followed an example from Xamarin (here: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/pick_image/) on how to allow the user to navigate their android device, and select an image. However the line
    using (ICursor cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null))
throws the error "error CS0103: The name 'ICursor' does not exist in the current context".

This is stooping any implementation of the methods for the cursor too.

Here's my code:

```
public class Profile : Activity
{   
    public static readonly int PickImageId = 1000;
    private ImageView _imageView;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Profile);
        _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += ButtonOnClick;

        _OKButton.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            string firstname,surname,country,city,IAmA,bio;
            firstname = _FirstNameBox.Text;
            surname = _SurnameBox.Text;
            country = _CountryBox.Text;
            city = _CityBox.Text;
            //IAmA = spinner_ItemSelected;
            IAmA = "Bassist";
            bio = "";

            sendProfileToCloud(firstname,surname,country,city,IAmA,bio);

        };
    }
    private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Intent = new Intent();
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
            Uri uri = data.Data;
            _imageView.SetImageURI(uri);

            string path = GetPathToImage(uri);
            Toast.MakeText(this, path, ToastLength.Long);
        }
    }

    private string GetPathToImage(Uri uri)
    {
        string path = null;
        // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
        string[] projection = new[] { Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data };
        using (ICursor cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null))
        {
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.